# CoreData misinterpreting object class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

When saving my core data context I have the following error.
I have really no idea where to start looking at, if you have even a lead...
Thank you.

PS: I checked that all types declared in .h files are the same as in my Data Model.

EDIT : I overwrote intValue in a category of NSDate. Now I see that timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is called on a NSNumber. I tried to put a breakpoint there but it gives no info (only save: is before my code). I also found out a way to know who is those famous objects : NSDate is an object (called lastCompute) in the same class as the NSNumber (called sleep). Their type match the types declarated in .h and data model. But it does not give me a hint on why CoreData calls intValue on an NSDate. Any lead ? Thanks

```
-[__NSDate intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3cba0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3cba0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ca35a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01df7313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ca50bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01c14966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01c14522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   CoreData                            0x00955b50 -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 2320
    6   CoreData                            0x009a7ebd -[NSSQLiteConnection updateRow:] + 365
    7   CoreData                            0x009a6e64 -[NSSQLConnection performAdapterOperations:] + 180
    8   CoreData                            0x009a6b0e -[NSSQLCore _performChangesWithAdapterOps:] + 494
    9   CoreData                            0x009a55ea -[NSSQLCore performChanges] + 410
    10  CoreData                            0x0099f038 -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] + 216
    11  CoreData                            0x0095d199 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 409
    12  CoreData                            0x00a0d70b -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 3691
    13  CoreData                            0x00995948 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 712
```

Comment: how about some code where you actually do saving?

Comment: Yeah no one can really interpret this as well as code.

Comment: -[__NSDate intValue]: unrecognized selector SAYS IT ALL. NSDate objects do not have an intValue function.

Comment: My problem is : I can't find where is this NSDate (thus where NSNumber is expected by Core Data).
@Eimantas / Nayefc : nothing fancy in my code, juste a lot of classes so I can't copy it here. What would you search in the code ?

Comment: Do you still think you need more code ?

Comment: some code from your project will surely going to give insight of your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.
I tried to remove the NSDate attribute. A new error came up (explained [here](http://blog.arunstephens.com/2011/03/05/binding-not-implemented-for-this-sqltype-7-core-data-and-iphone-os-3/)). So I checked all my [NSNumber numberWithSomething:] and I found out I was putting numbers created with int in attributes declared as float in data model.
I fixed all those mistakes, re-added the NSDate and now my app doesn't crash any more. I hope this was the solution even if it has nothing to do with intValue being called on an NSDate.

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because you call the method **intValue** on the **NSDate** Object *[NSDate date]* .
if you need to do something with the date as a time interval, than use

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

or if you need to compare two dates, than do something like this:

```
NSDate *startDate = (...some start date);
NSDate *endDate = (...some end date);

NSTimeInterval intervalInSeconds = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
```

Comment: I am not trying any of this. I am storing dates and numbers in my model and I don't think this should be a problem. My problem is finding on who is called intValue, I know on which object but I don't where is this object "in my code". Do you need more information to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed a property and the operations you're expecting aren't being performed correctly, it sounds like you're not handling versioning of the data model correctly.

Make sure you brush up on [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Even better, if your application hasn't been released to the public or a suite of testers and QA people then you can just start with a brand new database and not have to worry about versioning and migration just yet.

While starting from scratch is the easy way out, if you plan to use CoreData in the future you should really read and understand the versioning idea and the tools available for you in XCode 4.

Comment: I deleted the app and reinstalled it (multiple times). I still have the same problem.