# Core Data save exception on NSDate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, osx-snow-leopard

I've got this accessDate field, set as date type in the data model. I'm updating the accessDate with `object.accessDate = [NSDate date]` when accessing it.

It is a multithreaded application, and I've done 2 implementations, one with a shared NSManagedObjectContext and appropriate locks, and one with multiple contexts and appropriate merges, both having this exception throwing sporadically.

I've got NSZombieEnabled set in the process environment. I'm a bit out of ideas, so I'd be glad to hear some new suggestions.

EDIT: I forgot to add that it only occurs on Mac OS X 10.6

The exception is:

```
(gdb) po $rax
-[__NSCFDate longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ddf3020
```

the object does not look that suspicious:

```
(gdb) po 0x16ddf3020
2012-07-18 18:11:35 +0200
(gdb) po [0x16ddf3020 class]
__NSCFDate
```

and the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8973deea in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x00007fff803bc110 in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#2  0x00007fff803348ef in ___forwarding___ ()
#3  0x00007fff80330a38 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#4  0x00007fff831ad540 in -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] ()
#5  0x00007fff831f8e85 in -[NSSQLiteConnection updateRow:] ()
#6  0x00007fff831f801b in -[NSSQLConnection performAdapterOperation:] ()
#7  0x00007fff831f7f50 in -[NSSQLConnection performAdapterOperations:] ()
#8  0x00007fff831f7acb in -[NSSQLCore _performChangesWithAdapterOps:] ()
#9  0x00007fff831f680b in -[NSSQLCore performChanges] ()
#10 0x00007fff831f1259 in -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] ()
#11 0x00007fff831b4c8b in -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:] ()
#12 0x00007fff831b4051 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) executeRequest:withContext:] ()
#13 0x00007fff831e8123 in -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] ()
```

Comment: Are you sure zombies are actually turned on? You've set it in your scheme under "Diagnostics" or using the Zombies instrument?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. It's set to YES in "Variables to be set in the environment:" in the executable window (Xcode 3). It does occasionally kick in when needed.

Comment: Yikes, 10.6? Sounds like a defect fixed in a later version of OS X?

Comment: Maybe some error-catching has been added, but Core Data has been around for a while and I am not the first one to store NSDates in a database...

Comment: Is there a numeric field that you might be storing the date in by accident?

Comment: No, as I said the date is only set to [NSDate date]. And I verified that the object at the given address was of a date class. Besides that, a NSNumber would be glad to answer to a longLongValue selector...

Comment: I'm asking if there's a property on the object which is set to be numeric in the core data model which might be being set to a date value in code by mistake.

Comment: Ah. No, but I'd like it to be that simple, though :)

Comment: Yeah... Perhaps take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420404/coredata-misinterpreting-object-class ?

Comment: I think I am finding the bug right now ("think" because I could not manage to reproduce it in a unit test, so I cannot confirm it is really fixed). It would be a multi-threading issue because of a misconception on my part about managed object `@dynamic` properties accessors calling `primitiveValueForKey:` or not. I'll update as an answer when I become confident enough about it. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that "appropriate locks" was not true after all.

I have declared a property as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *accessDate;
```

and in the implementation file

```
@dynamic accessDate;
```

To guarantee proper locking on attribute I would have thought that

```
- (id)primitiveValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
  [[self managedObjectContext] lock];
  id value = [super primitiveValueForKey:key];
  [[self managedObjectContext] unlock];
  return value;
}
```

would be enough, but in fact synthesized Core Data properties do not call `primitiveValueForKey:` at all, that was a misconception of my part, so in fact the access was not properly locked. The answer might juste be that the synthesized Core Data accessor locks context on 10.7, and does not on 10.6.

So I have solved my problem by just reimplementing the accessor by hand:

```
- (NSDate *)accessDate
{
  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"accessDate"];
  NSDate *date = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"accessDate"];
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"accessDate"];  

  return date;
}
```